# Slow Camera Capture

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, camera, desktop-application

I am using Windows 8's media capture class to click a photo in a desktop application and copy it to clipboard.

My function takes two inputs as argument, 
1) the desired device (front, back or usb web cam) and 
2) the desired resolution

Here is the function:

```
async public void UseCamera(int x, int y)
    {
        MediaCapture _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        var _ImageFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreatePng();
        var _fileStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        MediaCaptureInitializationSettings _cameraSettings1 = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
        DeviceInformationCollection _deviceInformationCollection = null;
        IReadOnlyList<IMediaEncodingProperties> res;

        _deviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

        if (x > _deviceInformationCollection.Count - 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Device Not found");
        }

        else
        {
            _cameraSettings1.VideoDeviceId = _deviceInformationCollection[x].Id;
            _cameraSettings1.AudioDeviceId = "";
            _cameraSettings1.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
            _cameraSettings1.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;

            await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(_cameraSettings1);

            res = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);

            uint maxResolution = 0;
            List<int> indexMaxResolution = new List<int>();
            if (res.Count >= 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < res.Count; i++)
                {
                    VideoEncodingProperties vp = (VideoEncodingProperties)res[i];

                    if (vp.Width > maxResolution)
                    {
                        indexMaxResolution.Add(i);
                        maxResolution = vp.Width;
                    }
                }

                indexMaxResolution.Reverse();
                if (y > indexMaxResolution.Count())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Maximum supported resolution index : " + (indexMaxResolution.Count - 1).ToString());
                }

                //this is the part that I believe is the trouble maker


                else
                {
                    await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, res[indexMaxResolution.ElementAt(y)]);
                    await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(_ImageFormat, _fileStream);

                    Clipboard.SetImage(Image.FromStream(_fileStream.AsStream()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The function is working, but the problem is that it is incredibly slow.. it takes almost 4-5 seconds to capture a photo. Can anyone tell me where am i going wrong and how can I speed things up. Because I tested my camera, and it can take clicks @ almost 2 pics per second..

Answer (score 0):

If you move all the initialization and device information queries to an initialization function you might see an increase in speed.

In my experience gathering device information is slow.

Try to do as much as possible upfront so that when the time comes to capture, only the necessary things need to be done.

Comment: i tried that too.. i initialized all three cameras and listed their resolution before hand on program launch. Camera initialization and resolution indexing is being done pretty fast, i believe it is the actual capture that is slowing things down..

Comment: You could also try to keep the images in memory and write them only when needed. The clipboard might be slow too. This is the only thing that you can change as far as I know. Perhaps adding some timers might help you pin-point the slowest parts.